# R-Package not found for conda

Tags: python, r, anaconda, conda, r-mice

I have been trying to install the R-package "miceadds"  in my conda environment.

I ran `conda install r-miceadds`
But it keeps telling me

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - r-miceadds_3.11-6

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

However, I did go on https://anaconda.org and found the package. I am not sure what is going on ..
Is there a way otherwise to install "r-miceadds" locally and have it being used in my conda environment?

Any help appreciated, thanks a lot!

Comment: hello! Yes I have already tried that, it says All requested packages already installed. Then, when I try to run the file it says "miceadds package" missing.

Comment: If you're talking about [this](https://anaconda.org/f30a78ec8/r-miceadds), it looks like an R package, not Python? And the command mentioned on the page is `conda install -c f30a78ec8/label/testdeps r-miceadds`

Comment: @not_speshal it does not work. i just ran your command and it said again :PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - r-miceadds

Comment: [A recipe is now submitted](https://github.com/conda-forge/staged-recipes/pull/16905) to add it to the Conda Forge channel. However, it didn't just work out-of-the-box, so might be a few days before it becomes available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now available through Conda Forge. Try

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge r-miceadds
```